# What Search Operators can I use in Outlook in Office 365?

Tags: search, office-365, outlook-365

My organization moved its mail & other applications from Google Apps to Office 365 Business. Since then, I use the web based Outlook app that comes along with this subscription for my company emails.

I'm really missing the search operators that I was using in Google's Mail Application.

When I search for some name, in the Outlook App, I see that it uses some operators like `From:(John Doe) OR From:(johnDoe@example.com)`

What Other Operators can I use in the search Bar?

I'm basically looking for documentation like [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), but for Office 365's Outlook App

Comment: @pnuts: Can you post that as an Answer, so that I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many keywords such as From:, To:, Subject:, Date between: and so on.

The only place where these are mentioned, are on this third part blogpost: https://www.lifewire.com/search-mail-outlook-com-1170664